# Reflections on water incorrect

Tags: borderlands-2

I have noticed, especially in sanctuary, that the reflection in water does not match the actual buildings.
This is killing my OCD.

Is this an easter-egg, or am i just seeing things?

Comment: Are reflections enabled in your settings?  look for "disable reflections" here: http://www.gamefront.com/how-to-improve-borderlands-2-with-ini-file-tweaks/

Comment: It's currently unknown whether it's an easter egg or someone working on the art put the wrong reflection map on that location.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Reflections in nearly every game are pre-rendered to "cube maps." It is a cheap way of adding believable reflection without rendering said reflection every frame. Because it's not real time, the reflection breaks down when given anything but a cursory glance, especially when an actor walks into what should be reflected by the view. As such, it is the burden of the texture artist to choose/create and orient a cube map so that it best fits the expectation of the passing viewer. It's not a bug or a glitch, it's just an oversight that thankfully doesn't impact gameplay.

Source: CptnOblivious, Kotaku.

Comment: Could you put a link to your source? I'd like to read it too.